# inserting data from php to database mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I'm having a problem to insert data from php to database.

File is: **Patient.php**

Table name is: **patient_tbl**

inside of table is: **avatar** and **education**

here is inserting code: ***There is no problem with this following code, value of 'education' will be inserted to table***

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $this->_table;
$sql .= "education,";
$params = array(
  urlencode($patient->getEducation()),
);
return $this->exec($sql, $params);
}
```

But now here is my problem, ***"Avatar" don't insert to table***

The error message is: **"Unable to prepare query."**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $this->_table;
$sql .= "education, avatar, ";
$params = array(
  urlencode($patient->getEducation()),
  urlencode($patient->getAvatar()),
);
return $this->exec($sql, $params);
}
```

What's my prblem? I can't find a solution for this,.

I really appreciate your help.

Thank you

Comment: Well, for starters, the trailing `,` in your second query will cause a syntax error.

Comment: Print out the `$sql` and include it in the question.  My guess is that the answer will be obvious (such as as the lack of parentheses around the column names).

Comment: Well, This is error message: Unable to prepare query.

Comment: why are you using urlencode?

Comment: Instead of adding "[SOLVED]" to the title, you should accept the (an) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Base syntax sql query 'INSERT' is

```
INSERT [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
        VALUES (expression,...),(...)
```

If you use some parameters, you need add brackets as that:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $this->_table;
$sql .= "(education, avatar) VALUES (?, ?)";
$params = array(
  urlencode($patient->getEducation()),
  urlencode($patient->getAvatar()),
);
return $this->exec($sql, $params);
}
```

And write, what in $this->exec?

Comment: Yes you are right, it was a small question mark missed there, just this ((?))  you are right. Thank you so much :)